# Why there is an inappropriate Lisiting of Sort method in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have got a doubt in Sort option in List.

Input:
cricketers=["sachin", "kohli", "Dravid", "Ganguly", "laxman", "Sehwag"]

cricketers.sort()

print(cricketers)

Output:['Dravid', 'Ganguly', 'Sehwag', 'kohli', 'laxman', 'sachin']

So i wonder in a direct code how could i get a mismatch of sorting ? Can someone help me on this ? doesn't it consider only first letter of the word?

Comment: Uppercase letters come before lowercase letters.  Try this:  `"Z" < "a"`.  The result is `True`.  If you want a case-insensitive comparison, then you need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the list case insesitive, you can use custom `key=`:

```py
cricketers = ["sachin", "kohli", "Dravid", "Ganguly", "laxman", "Sehwag"]

cricketers.sort(key=str.lower)
print(cricketers)
```

Prints:

```
['Dravid', 'Ganguly', 'kohli', 'laxman', 'sachin', 'Sehwag']
```